# How can I make the query work with doctrine1 using symfony 1.4?

Tags: mysql, symfony, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I am trying to run the following query using Doctrine 1 with symfony 1.4 but it says `Couldn't find class (SELECT` with 500 Internal Error. Is there any way I can make it work with Doctrine:

```
SELECT location_id FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT location_id FROM location_feature_restriction WHERE feature_restriction_id IN(4,15,16)) as t1 
WHERE location_id 
NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT location_id FROM location_feature_restriction WHERE feature_restriction_id = 5);
```

Currently I have it like this but it's not working:

```
/**
 * Search for venues with selected features
 * @param Doctrine_Query $qry     The SQL query
 * @param array          $values  The form values
 */
protected function addSearchFeatures(Doctrine_Query $qry, array $values = array()) {
  // "Dry" and "Bespoke Hire" options
  $qryParams = array();
  $qryParts = array();

  if (in_array("bespoke_hire", $values["features"]) && $values["features"][array_search("bespoke_hire", $values["features"])]) {
    $qryParts[] = "q.bespoke_hire = :BESPOKE_HIRE";
    $qryParams["BESPOKE_HIRE"] = 1;
    unset($values["features"][array_search("bespoke_hire", $values["features"])]);
  }
  if (array_key_exists("dry_hire", $values["features"]) && $values["features"][array_search("dry_hire", $values["features"])]) {
    $qryParts[] = "q.dry_hire = :DRY_HIRE";
    $qryParams["DRY_HIRE"] = 1;
    $values["features"][array_search("dry_hire", $values["features"])];
  }
  if (count($qryParts)) {
    $qry->andWhere(implode(" OR ", $qryParts), $qryParams);
  }

  // Search for selected features
  if (count($values["features"])) {
    // If anyone need to features should be searched using the OR condition then comment having condtion from following line.
    if ($values["no_noise_restrictions"]) {
      $subSql = "SELECT location_id FROM 
                (SELECT DISTINCT location_id FROM LocationFeatureRestriction WHERE feature_restriction_id IN(".implode(',', $values["features"]).")) as t1 
                WHERE location_id 
                NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT location_id FROM LocationFeatureRestriction WHERE feature_restriction_id = 5)";
    } else {
      $subSql = "SELECT LocationFeatureRestriction.location_id 
         FROM LocationFeatureRestriction
         WHERE feature_restriction_id IN(".implode(',', $values["features"]).")
         GROUP BY location_id
         HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT feature_restriction_id) = ".count($values['features']);
    }

    $qry->andWhere('q.id IN ('.$subSql.')');
  }
}
```

Doctrine Error:
[image]
**UPDATE:**

I have simplified the query to the following but then it was giving error `Couldn't get short alias for`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT location_id FROM location_feature_restriction 
WHERE location_id NOT IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT location_id FROM location_feature_restriction 
WHERE feature_restriction_id = 5);
```

Then went ahead and added alias for the table but now it's giving error `Couldn't find class featureTable`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT location_id FROM location_feature_restriction 
WHERE location_id NOT IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT location_id FROM location_feature_restriction AS featureTable
WHERE featureTable.feature_restriction_id = 5);
```

Comment: Provide more PHP code, your current PHP is to minimal atleast show how the used variables ($qry and $values).  are set.

Comment: @RaymondNijland : Sure, Let me update the question.

Comment: @RaymondNijland: I have updated the question now. Please take a look at it.

Comment: You really should consider upgrade

Comment: @Mcsky: Yeah we are rewriting the whole site in Symfony 3.4 now but till it's completed we are sticking with the symfony 1.4 for now.

Comment: "`protected function addSearchFeatures(Doctrine_Query $qry`" -> "Doctrine_Query A Doctrine_Query object represents a DQL query. It is used to query databases for data in an object-oriented fashion. A DQL query understands relations and inheritance and is dbms independant." ( https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/doctrine1/latest/Doctrine_Query.html ) What you have isn't a DQL query but a normal SQL query.. in DQL query the normal SQL table names needs to be Object names. -> https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

Comment: Yikes.  Talk about a blast from the past.  Does Doctrine 1 support nested select statements?  Do you have other working code with "SELECT whatever FROM (SELECT" type queries?  The error message seems to imply it expects a class name for the FROM value.  If not then I would break up the query into individual queries.

Comment: "The error message seems to imply it expects a class name for the FROM value" Yes @Cerad just like i said in mine other comment. The variable `$qry` is a `Doctrine_Query` Object which works with DQL code not SQL code

Comment: @Cerad: Not really I am not sure if there are other working examples.

Comment: Is there anyway I can make it work with JOINS?

Comment: @RaymondNijland This question is about Doctrine 1.  Completely different than Doctrine 2.  No DQL.

Comment: "This question is about Doctrine 1. Completely different than Doctrine 2. No DQL" Notice the url link https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/doctrine1/latest/Doctrine_Query.html @Cerad there is `doctrine1` in it.. So it looks like Doctrine 1 has DQL.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Looks can be deceiving.  The issue here is really about nested select statements.  If you can make a working query then be all means post an answer.

Comment: I just want to achieve the same results, Query can be complex or simple but I don't have any idea right now how to make it work except using core PHP but I want to make it work with SQL query instead of doing it with PHP.

Comment: Can you people please take a look at it again?

Comment: Instead of passing in a `Doctrine_Query` object, pass in a `Doctrine_Manager` instance which is just a PDO object.  Get it like this: `Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection()->getDbh();`  With the PDO instance you can make raw SQL queries in prepared statement fashion, which is what it looks like you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real credit goes to **[@Kris Peeling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5305000/kris-peeling)** because he got my attention to this idea!

Seems like I just needed to get the array of ID's so I used `Doctrine_Manager (PDO)` to do the job.

Here is what I did to get the job done:

```
if (isset($arrValues['features']) && count($arrValues['features']) > 0) {
  $this->addSearchFeatures($qry, $arrValues);
} else {
  if ($arrValues['no_noise_restrictions']) {
    $subQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT LocationFeatureRestriction.location_id FROM LocationFeatureRestriction WHERE feature_restriction_id = 5";
    $qry->andWhere('q.id NOT IN ('.$subQuery.')');
  }
}

/**
 * Search for venues with selected features
 * @param Doctrine_Query $qry     The SQL query
 * @param array          $values  The form values
 */
protected function addSearchFeatures(Doctrine_Query $qry, array $values = array()) {
  // "Dry" and "Bespoke Hire" options
  $qryParams = array();
  $qryParts = array();

  if (in_array("bespoke_hire", $values["features"]) && $values["features"][array_search("bespoke_hire", $values["features"])]) {
    $qryParts[] = "q.bespoke_hire = :BESPOKE_HIRE";
    $qryParams["BESPOKE_HIRE"] = 1;
    unset($values["features"][array_search("bespoke_hire", $values["features"])]);
  }
  if (array_key_exists("dry_hire", $values["features"]) && $values["features"][array_search("dry_hire", $values["features"])]) {
    $qryParts[] = "q.dry_hire = :DRY_HIRE";
    $qryParams["DRY_HIRE"] = 1;
    $values["features"][array_search("dry_hire", $values["features"])];
  }
  if (count($qryParts)) {
    $qry->andWhere(implode(" OR ", $qryParts), $qryParams);
  }

  // Search for selected features
  if (count($values["features"])) {
    // If anyone need to features should be searched using the OR condition then comment having condtion from following line.

    // When No Noise Restrictions is checked in Licensing Category
    if ($values['no_noise_restrictions']) {
      $subSql = "SELECT DISTINCT location_id FROM location_feature_restriction WHERE feature_restriction_id IN(".implode(',', $values["features"]).") AND location_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT location_id FROM location_feature_restriction WHERE feature_restriction_id = 5)";

      $connection = Doctrine_Manager::connection();
      $statement = $connection->execute($subSql);
      $statement->execute();
      $resultset = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      $location_ids = array();
      foreach ($resultset as $each) {
        $location_ids[] = $each['location_id'];
      }

      if (count($location_ids)) {
        $qry->andWhere('q.id IN ('.implode(',', $location_ids).')');
      } else {
        $qry->andWhere('q.id IN (0)');
      }
    } else {
      // Otherwise check for the normal features
      $subSql = "SELECT LocationFeatureRestriction.location_id 
                 FROM LocationFeatureRestriction
                 WHERE feature_restriction_id IN(".implode(',', $values["features"]).")
                 GROUP BY location_id
                 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT feature_restriction_id) = ".count($values['features']);
      $qry->andWhere('q.id IN ('.$subSql.')');
    }

  }
}
```